# I need to stop a function applying to multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I recently added a function that helps me track the last Cell I modified In my Timecard Worksheet:

=CELL("address")

It tells me the last column and row that I entered data into making it easier to track. The problem is, It works on all my worksheets in that workbook, which means if I enter something in my other worksheet: Data entry. The =CELL("address") cell in Timecard responds to that input in Timecard. Resulting in me losing my place. If there is some way for me to restrict a function to one worksheet I haven't been able to find it in my search. Hopefully, I explained it well enough!

Open to alternative solutions as well. Even if there's something that colors a cell after entering, then removes the color when I edit another. That'd be just fine, thanks.

Comment: add the name of the worksheet.

Comment: In the brackets?

Comment: You will need VBA for this